# Doxygen/Graphviz diagrams have "text" that displays as rows of little boxes

Tags: fonts, doxygen, graphviz

Doxygen is generating inheritance and collaboration diagrams for my documentation in which text appears as rows of empty boxes: one box per letter. It appears that Graphviz, which Doxygen uses to generate diagrams, is trying to use a font that is missing or defective.

I've tried to research this in the Graphviz documentation, but the information is very fragmented. I've found a detailed description of the attributes Graphviz uses, but no hint of where they're stored or how to change them.

Can someone please help me understand enough to correct this problem?

I'm running Doxygen 1.8.7 (quite old, I know, but I'm stuck with it due to compatibility issues). Graphviz appears to be v2.20. OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Well like you wrote yourself the doxygen version is very old (April 2014), also the graphviz version is,  (very) old. The major question is what kind of compatibility issues are you running into? Also show a small reproducible problem that shows the problem would be essential as the question is is the problem on the doxygen side or on the Graphviz / dot side? To see the later it would be advantageous to see at least a `.dot` file generated by doxygen.

Comment: I collected and zipped the .dot files but it's not clear how to upload them. I don't see any "upload" or "attach" control on the page. /// Isolating the problem will be a major undertaking if I have to do it. The project is huge and its build process is complex, and I don't know it well enough to distinguish the parts I need to keep. I'd like to see if you can tell anything from the .dot files first.

Comment: Later - I learned more about this. There's a file named config in the Graphviz directory which has a bunch of settings like "png:cairo 10 [newline] ps:cairo -10 [newline]" etc. That looks like a font name to me! /// The Graphviz doc says it's distributed without fonts, but knows to look for them in C:\Windows\Fonts. I looked and found... no Cairo font. /// I tried changing "png:cairo" to "png:Tahoma" (since I'm generating .png files and Tahoma is a built-in Windows font). The .png files displayed text then, but... [continued]

Comment: ...it looked like placeholder text, and I got a lot of errors like, "Could not open image `<pathname>.../<filename>.png' generated by dot!"/// I found a Cairo font on Google, but it's an Arabic font, so I'm sure it's the wrong one. /// I found lots of documentation for font handling in Graphviz. Apparently its super-smart and OS-independent, so it's different from native font handling in Windows and every other supported system./// [continued]

Comment: Graphviz appears to be one of those programs where you have to learn almost everything to do almost anything. I don't expect to work directly with Graphviz again, so I hope you or someone can help me get past this without a lot of time investment. [end]

Comment: Like written before show where exactly the problem lies (but best is to upgrade doxygen and graphviz).

Comment: Jonathan, "cairo" isn't a font, it is a well used software package. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cairo_(graphics) ). I am not sure what is the problem, please attach a single dot file and an resulting image. For this you need to edit your question. There you can add the dot file as code and the image by drag & drop.

Comment: wizard, Albert already told me that and I replied that I CANNOT FIND AN "ATTACH" OR "UPLOAD" BUTTON ON THE PAGE. I don't need to be told to upload a file again. I need to know how to to it.

Comment: Albert, I should have been more clear in my original message. I said "compatibility issues" as shorthand for "a set of software tools that all of our projects must use, which are hard-coded to use that version." This is not the sort of compatibility issue that can be diagnosed and corrected. In my work situation, it's just a given. Therefore using a newer version of Doxygen is not an option. I need to diagnose and solve the font problem itself.